# Error in Oracle Coherence - "no storage-enabled nodes exist for service partitionedcache" while using Cohql in production

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence, distributed-cache

I am using Oracle Coherence in PartitionedCache mode. I am loading data to cache through my applications. For checking and monitoring purpose, I want  to use Cohql in Production environment to view the contents of cache. But, when I am using Cohql to view cache content, I am getting this error - "no storage-enabled nodes exist for service partitionedcache". Can any one point out what mistake I am doing?

I do not want to load any data through Cohql terminal, I just want to view the contents of existing cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to this paramter -Dcoherence.distributed.localstorage = false in the query.sh script of Coherence/bin folder.
Making this true solved the problem.